# Lambda expression - select single object with a IEnumerable<> property

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Is it possible to select a single object and populate a containing IEnumerable property with a single Lambda expression?

Something like this:

```
    var someViewModel = _repository.Table.Where(x => x.Id == someId)
       .Select(new ListViewModel(){
          GroupId = x.Group.Id,
          GroupTitle = x.Group.Title
          List = ?? // Select new SubViewModel and add it to IEnumerable<SubViewModel>
       })
```

The result I'm after is a new object (ListViewModel in this case) that contains 3 properties. "List" being a collection of newly selected objects.

Is this possible? Am I coming at this from the wrong angle?

Thanks!

**Update:**

Let me try again :) Keep in mind that my naming is fictional here. Given the following two classes I would like to construct a DB query using a Lambda expression which creates a single "ListViewModel" that contains a collection of "SubViewModel". Does this help clarify?

```
public class SubViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ListViewModel
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupTitle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SubViewModel> List { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: where will you get the subviewmodel from ?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand your question with no clue as to what your data model looks like. If you're trying to select a single object, just use `Single`...

Comment: Where is `Group` coming from?  Is this a separate table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but here is what I am thinking, you need to create a new IEnumberable and add the item to that collection.

```
var someViewModel = _repository.Table.Where(x => x.Id == someId)
                    .Select(new ListViewModel()
                            {
                                GroupId = x.Group.Id,
                                GroupTitle = x.Group.Title
                                List = new List<SubViewModel> { new SubViewModel(x) }
                            });
```